# Helm - not able to fetch jetstack/cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

Fetching the [deprecated cert-manager Helm chart from Github](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/cert-manager) into an untardir is easy:

```
helm fetch \
  --version v0.5.2 \
  --untar \
  --untardir charts \  
  stable/cert-manager
```

I have been trying to fetch [the up-to-date Helm chart from Jetstack](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/tree/master/deploy/charts/cert-manager) in the same manner:

```
helm fetch \
  --repo https://charts.jetstack.io \
  --untar \
  --untardir charts \
  jetstack/cert-manager
```

> Error: chart "jetstack/cert-manager" not found in https://charts.jetstack.io repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `--repo` flag, you should be able to fetch the chart without `jetstack/` prefix in your chart name.

```
helm fetch \
  --repo https://charts.jetstack.io \
  --untar \
  --untardir charts \
  cert-manager
```

Chart name prefix represents the [chart repo](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_repository/#charts), like `stable/`.
After running `helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io` first, you will be able to `fetch` chart without `--repo` flag.

```
helm fetch \
  --untar \
  --untardir charts \
  jetstack/cert-manager
```